# arrayIndexOutOfBounds exception when importing digitalPersona Fmd

Tags: java, arrays, sdk, indexoutofboundsexception, biometrics

Hello guys am currently working on a fingerPrint attendance software using digitalPersona UareU sdk java.i want to import Fmds stored in my database to use for identification but am getting an arrayIndexOutOfBounds exception 22, any contribution will be appreciated. below is my database code to get the fmds.

```
  public class Record {
    String userID;
    byte[] fmdBinary;

    Record(String ID, byte[] fmd) {
        userID = ID;
        fmdBinary = fmd;
    }
}
public List<Record> GetAllFPData() throws SQLException {
    List<Record> listUsers = new ArrayList<Record>();
    String sqlStmt = "Select * from " + tableName;
    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sqlStmt);
    while (rs.next()) {
        if (rs.getBytes(print1Column) != null)
            listUsers.add(new Record(rs.getString(userColumn), rs
                    .getBytes(print1Column)));
    }
    return listUsers;
}
///////////////
 try {
            db.Open();
            this.m_listOfRecords = db.GetAllFPData();
            for (FingerDB.Record record : this.m_listOfRecords) {
    //And this is the block that gives the error
    Fmd fmd = UareUGlobal.GetImporter().ImportFmd(record.fmdBinary,
    Fmd.Format.ANSI_378_2004,Fmd.Format.ANSI_378_2004);
    ///////////
    this.m_fmdList.add(fmd);

      }
            m_fmdArray = new Fmd[this.m_fmdList.size()];
            this.m_fmdList.toArray(m_fmdArray);
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            MessageBox
        .DpError("Failed to load FMDs from database.Please check 
         connection string in code.",
                            null);
            return;
        } catch (UareUException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            JOptionPane
                    .showMessageDialog(null, "Error importing fmd data.");
            return;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?
Ps. db could be null

Comment: thanks for the reply but db is not null i think the exception has something to do with the fmd format if the format is Fmd.Format.ANSI_378_2004 it gives that error but not when the format is Fmd.Format.DP_REG_FEATURE